# UIPasteboard.general.string takes too long

Tags: ios, swift, xcuitest

In my UI test, I have a test where I am using the UIPasteboard to throw the input around. Just before I use it, I store the current value of the pasteboard into a local temporary variable like so: `let currentClipboard = UIPasteboard.general.string ?? ""` and it will be restored again at the end of the test like so: `UIPasteboard.general.string = currentClipboard`. However, sometimes the `let currentClipboard = UIPasteboard.general.string ?? ""` line takes forever to complete, if at all. I've waited like 1-2 minutes and it still stuck there. I know this because I actually added a breakpoint right below that line and it was never called. Can anybody tell me what's wrong with my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I've faced the same issue in the simulator only.
If you're testing in simulator then just reset the simulator and it'll start working fine. And I didn't find this type of issue in the real device.

Comment: IC. Thanks for the answer. You are right, it only happens in simulator because it's only for UITesting. But it still happens even though I've restarted simulator so many times.

Comment: @BawenangRukmokoPardianPutra You can workaround with reset/format instead of restart.